# Azure Deployment IDs and URLs

Tags: azure

We have a Windows Azure Cloud Service with two instances per deployment. Currently, the deployments are hooked up like this:

Deployment ID `a1a1...` is in the production slot.

Deployment ID `b2b2...` is in the staging slot.

The Web Roles in these deployments have a status page, which can be reached like this:

```
http://a1a1... .cloudapp.net/status
http://b2b2... .cloudapp.net/status
```

On this status page we are displaying, among other things, the deployment ID, which we look up programmatically like this:

```
if (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
{
    return Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId;
}
```

The strange thing is that this status page displays the deployment ID `b2b2...`, no matter which of the two URLs we are invoking.

**Shouldn't `http://a1a1... .cloudapp.net/status` be displaying `a1a1...` as the deployment ID?**

Btw: Our domain `http://www.ourdomain.com/status` shows the correct deployment ID `a1a1...`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a VIP swap to swap your production and staging services?  There are a few reasons why you might be hitting this, but if you have done a VIP swap then I would say the most likely is that your requests to the 2 different URLs are actually going to the same hosted service.  This is typically caused by TCP connections staying open between the client and the server after the VIP swap, which means that HTTP requests will continue to be sent over that same TCP connection.

The first thing I would do to troubleshoot this is to RDP to both services and check the IIS logs to see if the requests are going to the same service.

Comment: Yes, we have done many VIP swaps, but the last one was several days ago, so I think most TCP connections should have been renewed since then, shouldn't they?. The two requests really are going to the same machine, we checked on that.